# Pigeon Hole Principle - proof of d as a positive integer

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Let $d$ be a positive integer and consider any set $A$ of $d+1$ positive integers. Show that there exists two different numbers $x, y\ \epsilon\ A$ so that $ x \mod\ d = y \mod\ d$ and $x =/= y$.

> Remainders after division by $d$ must fall in the range $0 ≤ r ≤ d −
> > 1$; there are precisely $d$ different remainders. By the pigeonhole
>   principle, at least two of any collection of $d + 1$ integers must
>   have the same remainder when divided by $d$.

I know I have to use the pigeon hole principle for this, but I'm unsure as to how to start this. Any help would be great

Comment: HINT: What are the possible values of $x\bmod d$? How many of them are there?

Comment: There are only $d $ different equivalence classes modulo $d $. What you have is $d+1$ equivalence classes (one for each element of $A $), so two of them must be equal.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  updated my post

Comment: $Z_d$is a partition of Z in d classes and any integer must be in one of them.